# In Pyside: QProcess.write(u'Test') returns 0L

Tags: python, string, unicode, pyside, qprocess

My understanding is that in Pyside QString has been dropped. One can write a Python string into a QLineEdit, and when the QLineEdit is read, it is returned as a unicode string (16-bits per character).

Trying to write this string from my Gui process to a sub-process started using QProcess does not seem to work and just returns 0L (see below). If one changes the unicode string back to a Python string using the `str()` function, then `self.my_process.write(str(u'test'))` now returns 4L. This behaviour does not seem correct to me.

Would it be possible for someone to explain why `QProcess.write()` does not seem to work on unicode strings?

```
(Pdb) PySide.QtCore.QString()
*** AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'QString'
(Pdb) self.myprocess.write(u'test')
0L
(Pdb) self.myprocess.write(str(u'test'))
4L
(Pdb)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PySide has never provided classes like QString, QStringList, QVariant, etc. It has always done implicit conversion to and from the equivalent python types - that is, in PyQt terminology, it only implements the [v2 API](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/incompatible_apis.html) (see [PSEP 101](https://qt.gitorious.org/pyside/pseps/source/cf7430368098e1b9c87c2233dff8a00ef7059ad2:psep-0101.txt) for more details).

However, the behaviour of QProcess when attempting to write unicode strings seems somewhat broken in PySide compared with PyQt4. Here's a simple test in PyQt4:

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Sep 24 2014, 18:26:21) 
[GCC 4.9.1 20140903 (prerelease)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PyQt4 import QtCore
>>> QtCore.PYQT_VERSION_STR
'4.11.2'
>>> p = QtCore.QProcess()
>>> p.start('cat'); p.waitForStarted()
True
>>> p.write(u'fóó'); p.waitForReadyRead()
3L
True
>>> p.readAll()
PyQt4.QtCore.QByteArray('f\xf3\xf3')
```

So it seems that PyQt will implicitly encode unicode strings as 'latin-1' before passing them to `QProcess.write()` (which of course expects either `const char *` or a `QByteArray`). If you want a different encoding, it must be done explicitly:

```
>>> p.write(u'fóó'.encode('utf-8')); p.waitForReadyRead()
5L
True
>>> p.readAll()
PyQt4.QtCore.QByteArray('f\xc3\xb3\xc3\xb3')
```

Now let's see what happens with PySide:

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Sep 24 2014, 18:26:21) 
[GCC 4.9.1 20140903 (prerelease)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PySide import QtCore, __version__
>>> __version__
'1.2.2'
>>> p = QtCore.QProcess()
>>> p.start('cat'); p.waitForStarted()
True
>>> p.write(u'fóó'); p.waitForReadyRead()
0L
^C
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyboardInterrupt
```

So: no implicit encoding, and the process just blocks instead of raising an error (which would seem to be a bug). However, re-trying with explicit encoding works as expected:

```
>>> p.start('cat'); p.waitForStarted()
True
>>> p.write(u'fóó'.encode('utf-8')); p.waitForReadyRead()
5L
True
>>> p.readAll()
PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('fóó')
```

Comment: Thank you; good explanation; since almost everything in Qt in Pyside is unicode, I would have thought that QProcess.write() would have handled unicode strings without requiring encoding into a different format; I think I agree with your comment that Pyside seems broken when using QProcess. Currently, I have not figured out how to attach a debugger to the child process when it is Python; this would help understand when QProcess blocks. I wonder if dbus-python would be a better way to communicate between process's?

Comment: @bit_pusher. At some point, unicode objects will always have to be encoded to bytes before being written; there is no way to write them directly. The only issue is whether the encoding is done implicitly. Personally, I would always avoid this, and make sure the correct encoding is used by setting it myself. Explicit is better than implicit (especially when it comes to encodings).

Comment: I don't quite understand why unicode can not be written directly, as to my understanding they are "encoded to bytes". My understanding is most unix's and Python use UTF-8 unicode which does specify exactly what the bytes are for each character of most languages, and if this is true, these UTF-8 bytes should be sent. I also think that UTF-8 can be detected fairly reliably? Shouldn't a failing operation (in this case QProcess.write() give some feedback? I suspect a textstream rather than a binary stream is being used by QProcess; Could someone please direct me to documentation on these issues?

Comment: Well, as I said, and you repeated, unicode cannot be written directly because it has to be encoded to bytes first. Unicode objects do not themselves have an encoding; they just map code points to characters. In order to tranfer unicode from one place to another, it has to be encoded in a standard format, and sent in the form of bytes (UTF == Unicode Transformation Format). The big question is always: which encoding should be used? If you don't decide this yourself, you are forcing Python to guess, and it is impossible to guarantee that it will always get it right.

Comment: A good starting point for understanding the issues is [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)